# It is possible to put entity as subelement in DTD declaration?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm working on map structure which should contain static elements stored in separate *.ent files that are DTD entities. The *.ent file should contain xml element declaration:

```
<tree>
 <type>...</type>
 <heigth>..</height>
</tree>
```

And now I want to add entities as subelements in DTD declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT map (staticElement+)>
<!ENTITY tree SYSTEM "tree.ent">
<!ENTITY wall SYSTEM "wall.ent">
<!ELEMENT staticElemnet (element+)>
<!ENTITY element (&tree;|&wall;)>
```

Finally, the xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "map.dtd">
<map>
  <staticElement>
    <element>
      <tree>
       ...
      </tree>
    </element>
  </staticElement>
</map>
```

How should this be done?

Comment: @Tomalak You are right. I corrected it.